# How can I sort a set of numbers into evenly distributed buckets?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given a set of numbers [5,2,6,7,8,1,1,2,3,3,6,1,2], group them so that the sum of all numbers in each group is less than 10 and the numbers are most evenly distributed.

Some examples:
input [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] outputs [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

input [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] outputs [[1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1]]

input [5,5,1] outputs [[5,1], [5]]

input [5,1] outputs [[5,1]]

input [6,6,6,6] outputs [[6], [6], [6], [6]]

I have looked at doing bucket sort, gale shapley, knapsack and can not find a stable algorithm that works for this. I initially started doing a pure bucket sort by determining the number of buckets = ceil(sum(input) / 10) but realized that does not work in the 6s example above because I was getting 3 buckets when I needed 4.

Comment: "the numbers are most evenly distributed. " explain this with some good test cases.

Comment: check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62661283/13638059) it might help you